# Salesforce DX CLI commands to deploy a feature from Git to sandbox

Tags: salesforce

I have a question on using salesforce DX for deployment to sandbox. On one of the trailheads, I saw an option to deploy from local salesforce dx project to sandbox.

But I am looking for a way to deploy from git or any other VCS to a sandbox. How do we do that using Salesforce DX?

Answer (score 0):

Deploying from VCS or from your local computer would both use the same command line approach. I'm not allowed to comment, but could you explain the difference please?